# Is Expression Blend required when you have VS2010?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

There have been posts on this site in the past that say that programming in WPF is difficult without Expression Blend?

Is this still the case with VS2010, or does this new IDE have features that make WPF a lot easier?

Comment: I have never used Expression Blend. The VS2010 XAML designer has been pretty great for my WPF development so far. But this is just me, of course :)

Comment: I dont think its necessary to have Expression blend for programmers. If you are a programmer/developer you want to write XAML in visual studio not use the visual editor. If you are more of a designer then maybe Expression is the tool to use.

Comment: You need Expression if you are a **divigner** (developer*designer = devigner).

Answer (score 5):

I am a developer, but there is no way I would develop XAML applications of any kind without Expression Blend.  The value is far too great and not limited to just pretty graphics.  Templates, data binding, resource management, layout, rapid design, visualization, etc. are all vastly superior experiences in Blend.

I really struggle with developer rejection of Blend.  Aside from the fact that it isn't free or included with Visual Studio there are no compelling reasons to ignore such a powerful tool.  Yes, it is different than Visual Studio, and yes, there is a learning curve, but once you know how to use it Blend is unquestionably the right choice.

I understand developers need help through that learning curve.  I also understand that Blend is unlike other tools we have used in the past: believe me, I've been there!  That's why I wrote the book "Expression Blend in Action: a developer's guide", to help developers over this hurdle.  This isn't meant to be an advertisement so I'm not providing the link, but if you're interested you can find it at Manning.com.

Comment: I think of Blend as an extension of Visual Studio.  I usually have both open when working on any XAML project.

Comment: Joel it is included with the two (I believe) top MSDN subs, but also one can grab the free version of Blend with the free VS Express version for Windows Phone dev.

Comment: Yes, Blend (without SketchFlow) comes with MSDN Premium and Blend (with SketchFlow) comes with MSDN Ultimate.  Each is part of Expression Studio but not available separately.  Yes, Blend for WP7 is free but limited to phone projects.  There is also a free 60-day trial available at http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/.

Comment: I understand the advantages of Blend.  But if I am doing a rather simple "Windows Forms" type of application with a static UI (edit box, etc), can I do without Blend?  Thanks.

Comment: You certainly can, I just wouldn't want to.  This is my personal preference, there are lots of people who code XAML by hand in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you are using WPF for.

If you are writing a line-of-business CRUD application, then there is no need for expression blend at all.

I've been programming in WPF for years, and was only introduced to Expression blend a month ago.
It definitely makes some things easier, in particular animations or vector graphics.

But, if you've become comfortable typing directly into the XAML editor (as most developers are), then it really isn't necessary to do your job.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why people are comparing the development of WPF apps on Visual Studio and Expression. The Simple answer to this question is when you need to do vector designing for your application, Expression Blend is the resource for it. You can't design a control in WPF as per your requirement. Expression Blend supports the WPF text engine with advanced OpenType typography and ClearType, vector-based 2D widgets, and 3D widgets with hardware acceleration via DirectX.

In essence, it is a user interface design tool developed and sold by Microsoft for creating graphical interfaces for web and desktop applications that blend the features of these two types of applications. It is an interactive, WYSIWYG front-end for designing XAML-based interfaces for Windows Presentation Foundation and Silverlight applications.

Expression Blend supports developing Microsoft Silverlight browser-based Rich Internet Applications providing animation, vector graphics, interactivity and video playback capabilities

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, it's not required.  But Expression Blend is a great UI design tool that can simplify your UI development.   It's a tool, like any other, optimized for doing certain tasks.  Developers pick tools based on what they do for us. Think about unit tests.  Using a Unit Testing framework saves us a lot of time and effort, as the framework people have optimized their tool for the task.

For me, Blend is my goto tool for these features.

- Animations and Timelines
- Gradient Editing
- Control Templates
- Template PARTS
- Visual State Manager
- Resources and Resource Dictionaries
- Styles
- Sample Data, with DataBinding
- Shape Combining
- Paths, Layout Paths

Here is just one example. Setting up an multipart animation in Blend might be a two minute job.  Writing the same Animation logic in Visual Studio XAML editor may take 5-10x longer.  Plus Blend has an animation preview.  In VS I have to compile and run my app to see if the animation works as intended.  On big projects that build time eats into my productivity.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit yes and no, you can do Xaml development without Blend but for somethings Blend is a better solution. Personally I stick with VS2010 unless I know that I'm gonna be doing some custom styling or custom UI in general.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned programming in WPF so take it that you are not a UI designer. Go with Visual Studio, theres's nothing you cant to in Visual studio that you can do with Expression Blend.

Comment: That's a bit misleading. What you can do 'visually' is fairly substantial. It may be the case that you or he doesn't need or use the features, but you're hardly going to draw anything other then primatives in VS with any ease. For instance, trying to do complex overlays, matching certain types of color, complex pen paths and the like might be possible in VS but even saying it would be difficult to do would be understating.

Comment: @user179700 My answer was heavily biased towards developers/programmers but I still haven't found much use of Expression in my work. I think programming in with WPF with Visual Studio is easy enough not to look for other tools.

Answer (score 1):

Blend is not required for WPF or Silverlight.  However, it makes some things a heck of a lot easier.  Specifically:

- Animations
- Extracting control templates
- Styling controls without having to build and run everything

You can do all of these things without Blend, but it's not as easy.  For example, you can write a WPF program that extracts the default template for a control and then displays it as text.  Or if you use Blend, you can click a button.  I find that without Blend, I have to constantly do edit/build/run cycles and that takes time. ("Nope, that color isn't right.  What if I just tweak it this way a little bit..." and then I'm off to get a cup of coffee as the whole thing builds and runs just so I can check a color.)

Blend saves me time and makes my life easier -- that's why I use it or any other tool.